# How Google OAuth Client library refreshes access token using refresh token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, integration, google-oauth-java-client

So I have been working on Google's OAuth client library for integrating my application with another web service. Type of access is offline. So, I have both the access token and refresh token as a Stored Credential on my side.

The question is, do I need to perform any manual steps for refreshing the access token using the refresh token once the existing access token is expired or Google client library itself will regenerate it automatically.

I saw some posts where they will refresh the tokens automatically. But I decompiled most of the authentication related classes and checked for the triggering point for this refresh action. Unfortunately I couldn't find any. Please assist me on this.

My apologies for improper verbose if any.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the library will refresh everything automatically  rather than decompile why not just check the source code https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client

Comment: @DaImTo Hi. Thanks for the reply. I checked the source code too. But I couldn't find the specific place or snippet from where they initialize this refresh. Apparently, this should be handled when the response code is not equal t0 200,201 etc. etc. when the API call is made using an expired access token Or they should run a scheduler to check whether the token is expired. I may be wrong. But I would like to know how this happens, this automatic refresh of credentials.

Comment: the library automatically checks if the access token is within five minutes of expiring to avoid any issues with clock skew.  You dont need to do anything

Comment: @DaImTo Yes.. Thanks.